# Using OpenBox window manger in Tails OS

Tags: tails

Im a little new to this so I apologize if i am using it improperly but i recently installed Tails OS and i dont like the way the desktop looks so Ive been trying to use Openbox window manager within it. I saw in many articles and tutorials that after you install openbox you just select to use it when logging in but the settings button doesnt seem to be present when logging in with tails. Id like to get openbox setup in my persistence volume to use anytime i log in, but i cant figure out how. The thing i theorized about was running virtualbox within tails and using Whonix within that virtual machine but it think thats even more of a stretch. Id love some help on this topic, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Tails is still immature, so no wonder why you're having the trouble you're asking about. To achieve a **way** better security and user experience you need to use [QubesOS](https://www.qubes-os.org/) and Tor combined - try it and forget the Tails(hit) :) To make things really secure you arise Tor **not at dom0** as it said in many quickjump guides, but on a *separate* VM container and then you're just using it as a router for the rest of the system. If you need to use Tor protection for dom0 you should do this through the proxy functionality **only** - routing and thansparent proxying can be easier to set up but it will break some things on dom0 and some security will be lost.

Comment: Thanks, Isnt Qubes heavy though. Also, isnt it possible for me to run any old distro and manually connect the tor network and run it live from usb?

Comment: Qubes is quite a lightweight even for a netbook - unless **you** will make it heavy by installing tons of bloatware packages, but any distribution will become heavyweight if this happens. About making your own live distro - sure, can! but it's a bit laborious comparing to pre-made one like Qubes. Yes, Tails is lighter than Qubes, but *just a little bit*, so don't be concerned about it